# In Django I have written the html to edit a form this during retrieving the values from database by value={{ i.full_name}} it shows only first name

Tags: python, html, django, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ev7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJcNs.png) This is my edit.html code and during retrieving the values from database and showing in this html form it shows only first name when I am writing value={{ i.full_name}} why not the full name during filling up form I have included the full name I think there is some mistake after white space it cant read the characters anymore For example when filling the form I have written Rowan Atkinson but during editing the form I am getting only Rowan. You can see in the image which I have attached.

```
<section class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 mb-5">
        <h2 class="mb-4 text-center">Update Candidate Details</h2>
          
        <form method="POST" action="/update/ {{i.id}}/"  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="p-4 border rounded" onsubmit="myFunction()" >
        {%  csrf_token %}
          {% comment %} <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="UabxqpD8HGPOu1ZSFnIHAPbMtRgWBAnVHEs8bLDx0HnxN6uhG3LyYvZShvcx1ekn"> {% endcomment %}
          
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="full_name">Full Name :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value ={{ i.full_name}} name="full_name" id="id_full_name" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            </div>
          </div>   

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="recruiter_name">Recruiter Name :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{ i.recruiter_name }} name="recruiter_name" id="id_recruiter_name" placeholder="Enter Recruiter Name">
            </div>
          </div>     
  

          {% comment %} <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
            <label class="text-black" for="id_last_name">Last Name :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="id_last_name" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            </div>
          </div> {% endcomment %}
        
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="email">Email :</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control"  value ={{i.email }} name="email" id="id_email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="noticeperiod">Notice Period (in Days) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.noticeperiod }} name="noticeperiod" id="notice_period" placeholder="Notice Period">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="preferredlocation">Current Location :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.preferredlocation}} name="preferredlocation" id="preferred_location" placeholder="Enter Current Location">
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="expectedlocation">Expected Location :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.expectedlocation}} name="expectedlocation" id="expected_location" placeholder="Enter Multiple Locations seperated by comma">
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="currentctc">Current CTC (Per Annum) :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"   value ={{i.currentctc }} name="currentctc" id="current_ctc" placeholder="Current CTC">
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="expectedctc">Expected CTC (Per Annum) : </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  value ={{i.expectedctc }} name="expectedctc" id="expected_ctc" placeholder="Expected CTC">
            </div>
          </div>
          
           <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" for="status">Status : </label> </br>

              <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control"  value ={{i.status }}>
                <option value="CV Received">CV Received</option>
                <option value="Submitted to Client">Submitted to Client</option>
                <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
                <option value="Offered">Offered</option>
                <option value="Joined">Joined</option>
                <option value="Closed">Closed</option>
                <option value="Payment Received">Payment Received</option>
                
              </select>
              {% comment %} <input type="text" class="form-control" name="status" id="status1" placeholder="Enter Application Status"> {% endcomment %}
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <label class="text-black" >Upload CV</label></br>
              <input type="file"  name="cv" id="cv1"   value ={{ i.cv}} >
            </div>
          </div>


      
          <div class="row form-group mb-4">
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value={{i.gender}}>
                
                <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value={{i.gender}}>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="row form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" value="Update" id ="submit" class="btn px-4 btn-primary text-white">

               {% comment %} <a href="{% url 'jobapp:jobconfirm' %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</a> {% endcomment %}
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is my views.py

```
#delete
def delete(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    i.delete()
    return redirect('account:dboard')

#edit
def edit(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    context = {
        'i' : i
    }
    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', context)
    
#update
def update(request, id):
    i = ApplyForm.objects.get(id = id)
    i.full_name = request.POST['full_name']
    i.email = request.POST['email']
    i.noticeperiod = request.POST['noticeperiod']
    i.preferredlocation = request.POST['preferredlocation']
    i.expectedlocation = request.POST['expectedlocation']
    i.currentctc = request.POST['currentctc']
    i.expectedctc= request.POST['expectedctc']
    i.recruiter_name = request.POST['recruiter_name']
    i.status = request.POST['status']
    i.gender = request.POST['gender']
    i.cv = request.FILES['cv']
    i.save()
    return redirect('account:dboard')
```

And my models.py

```
class ApplyForm(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    noticeperiod = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    preferredlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    currentctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    recruiter_name = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 300,  null=True, choices= CATEGORY_CHOICES )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

That means after white space I am not able to retrieve the characters I dont know what to do what's happening also I am not getting data for choice field and file field i.e. Upload Cv , gender , status fields I am getting data from the other fields but after space of any text I am not getting the characters I have attached an image for this.

Comment: Use quotes: `value="{{ i.full_name}}"` As a best practice _always_ use quotes with HTML attributes as there might be _white spaces_ in the values.

Comment: Please just use Django Forms instead of writing the form markup manually.

Comment: ya django forms is okay But I have already created this Okay I will try with django forms

Comment: Yes its working when I included the quotes but can't retrieve the value of two choice fields that is status and gender and one file field that is upload cv what can I do for this ? according to my code what are the things I can do.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still actual you can solve it:

For '**Status**' field:

```
<select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
    <option value="CV Received"{% if i.status == 'CV Received' %} selected {% endif %}>CV Received</option>
    <option value="Submitted to Client"{% if i.status == 'Submitted to Client' %} selected {% endif %}>Submitted to Client</option>
    <option value="Rejected"{% if i.status == 'Rejected' %} selected {% endif %}>Rejected</option>
    <option value="Offered"{% if i.status == 'Offered' %} selected {% endif %}>Offered</option>
    <option value="Joined"{% if i.status == 'Joined' %} selected {% endif %}>Joined</option>
    <option value="Closed"{% if i.status == 'Closed' %} selected {% endif %}>Closed</option>
    <option value="Payment Received"{% if i.status == 'Payment Received' %} selected {% endif %}>Payment Received</option>
</select>
```

For '**Gender**' field:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" {% if i.gender == 'male' %} checked {% endif %}>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="male">Male</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female" {% if i.gender == 'female' %} checked {% endif %}>
    <label class="form-check-label" for="female">Female</label>
</div>
```

For uploaded **CV**:

```
<div class="col-md-12 mb-3 mb-md-0">
    {% if i.cv %}
        <a href="{{ i.cv.url }}" target="_blank" id="a_link">{{ i.cv }}</a>
    {% endif %}
    <label class="text-black" >Upload CV</label></br>
    <input type="file" name="cv" id="cv1">
</div>
```